# EventEmitter memory leak detected: Proper way to pass CSV data to multiple modules?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I am dipping my toe into using different npm modules my own way whereas before I just executed already created gulpfiles. The npm module [penthouse](https://github.com/pocketjoso/penthouse) loads a webpage and determines the above the fold CSS for that page. I am trying to take that module and use it with a site crawler so I can get the above the fold css for all pages, and store that CSS in a table.

So essentially I am:

- Crawling a site to get all the urls
- capturing the page id from each url
- storing pages & their id's in a CSV
- load the CSV and pass each URL to penthouse
- take penthouse output and store it in a table

So I am fine up until the last two steps. When I am reading the CSV, I get the error `possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit`.

The stack trace points [here](https://github.com/pocketjoso/penthouse/blob/master/lib/index.js#L134) at line 134. After reading about the error, it makes sense because I see a bunch of event listeners being added, but I don't see penthouse ever really executing and closing the event listeners.

It works just fine standalone as expected (Running penthouse against a single page then exiting). But when I execute the code below to try and loop through all URLs in a csv, it spits out the memory leak error twice, and just hangs. None of my console.log statements in the following script are executed.

However, I added console.log to the end of the penthouse index.js file, and it is executed multiple times (where it adds event listeners), but it never timeouts or exits.

So it's clear I am not integrating this properly, but not sure how to proceed. What would be the best way to force it to read one line in the CSV at a time, process the URL, then take the output and store it in the DB before moving onto the next line?

```
const fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('fast-csv');
var penthouse = require('penthouse'),
    path = require('path');

 var readUrlCsv = function() {
  var stream = fs.createReadStream("/home/vagrant/urls.csv");

  var csvStream = csv()
      //returns single line from CSV
      .on("data", function(data) {

        // data[0]: table id, data[1]: page type, data[2]: url
        penthouse({
            url : data[2],
            css : './dist/styles/main.css'

        }, function(err, criticalCss) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
            console.log('do we ever get here?'); //answer is no

            if (data[1] === 'post') {

              wp.posts().id( data[0] ).post({
                  inline_css: criticalCss
              }).then(function( response ) {
                console.log('saved to db');
              });
            } else {
              wp.pages().id( data[0] ).page({
                  inline_css: criticalCss
              }).then(function( response ) {
                  console.log('saved to db');
              });
            }
        });
      })
      .on("end", function(){
           console.log("done");
      });

  return stream.pipe(csvStream);
};
```

**UPDATE**

Changed my method to look like below so it processes all rows first, but still throws the same error. Writes "done" to the console, and immediately spits out the memory warning twice.

```
var readUrlCsv = function() {
  var stream = fs.createReadStream("/home/vagrant/urls.csv");
  var urls = [];
  var csvStream = csv()
      .on("data", function(data) {
        // data[0]: table id, data[1]: page type, data[2]: url
        urls.push(data);        
      })
      .on("end", function(){
           console.log("done");
           buildCriticalCss(urls);
      });

  return stream.pipe(csvStream);
};

var buildCriticalCss = function(urls) {
  //console.log(urls);
  urls.forEach(function(data, idx) {
    //console.log(data);
    penthouse({
            url : data[2],
            css : './dist/styles/main.css',
            // OPTIONAL params
            width : 1300,   // viewport width
            height : 900,   // viewport height
            timeout: 30000, // ms; abort critical css generation after this timeout
            strict: false, // set to true to throw on css errors (will run faster if no errors)
            maxEmbeddedBase64Length: 1000 // charaters; strip out inline base64 encoded resources larger than this
        }, function(err, criticalCss) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
            console.log('do we ever finish one?');
            if (data[1] === 'post') {
              console.log('saving post ' + data[0]);
              wp.posts().id( data[0] ).post({
                  inline_css: criticalCss
              }).then(function( response ) {
                console.log('saved post to db');
              });
            } else {
              console.log('saving page ' + data[0]);
              wp.pages().id( data[0] ).page({
                  inline_css: criticalCss
              }).then(function( response ) {
                  console.log('saved page to db');
              });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

**Update 2**

I took the simple approach to control the amount of concurrent processes spawned.

```
var readUrlCsv = function() {
  var stream = fs.createReadStream("/home/vagrant/urls.csv");
  var urls = [];
  var csvStream = csv()
      .on("data", function(data) {
        // data[0]: table id, data[1]: page type, data[2]: url
        urls.push(data);        
      })
      .on("end", function(){
           console.log("done");
           //console.log(urls);
           buildCriticalCss(urls);
      });

  return stream.pipe(csvStream);
};


function buildCriticalCss(data) {
    var row = data.shift();
    console.log(row);
    penthouse({
        url : row[2],
        css : './dist/styles/main.css',
        // OPTIONAL params
        width : 1300,   // viewport width
        height : 900,   // viewport height
        timeout: 30000, // ms; abort critical css generation after this timeout
        strict: false, // set to true to throw on css errors (will run faster if no errors)
        maxEmbeddedBase64Length: 1000 // charaters; strip out inline base64 encoded resources larger than this
    }, function(err, criticalCss) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('err');
      }
      // handle your criticalCSS
      console.log('finished');
      console.log(row[2]);
      // now start next job, if we have more urls
      if (data.length !== 0) {
        buildCriticalCss(data);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Using recursion to assure sequential processing is rarely the "right" way to do it due to the reason I describe in the update to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're seeing is a default printed to the console by node's [event](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js) library if more than the allowed number of event listeners are defined for an instance of EventEmitter. It does ***not*** indicate an actual memory leak. Rather it is displayed to make sure you're aware of the *possibility* of a leak.

You can see this by checking the event.EventEmitter source code at lines [20](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L20) and [244](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L244).

To stop EventEmitter from displaying this message and since `penthouse` does not expose its specific EventEmitter, you'll need to set the default allowed event emitter listeners to something larger than its default value of `10` using:

```
var EventEmitter=require('event').EventEmitter;

EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners=20;
```

Note that according to Node's documentation for [EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_eventemitter_defaultmaxlisteners), this will change the maximum number of listeners for ***all*** instances of EventEmitter, including those that have already been defined previous to the change.

Or you could simply ignore the message.

Further to the hanging of your code, I'd advise gathering all the results from the parsing of your CSV into an array, and then processing the array contents separately from the parsing process.

This would accomplish two things: It would allow you to

1. be assured the entire CSV file was valid before you started processing, and
2. instrument debugging messages while processing each element, which would give you deeper insight into how each element of the array was processed.

**UPDATE**

As noted below, depending on how many URLs you're processing, you're probably overwhelming Node's ability to handle all of your requests in parallel.

One easy way to proceed would be to use eventing to marshall your processing so your URLs are processed sequentially, as in:

```
var assert=require('assert'),
    event=require('events'),
    fs=require('fs'),
    csv=require('fast-csv');
    penthouse=require('penthouse');

var emitter=new events.EventEmitter();

/** Container for URL records read from CSV file.
 * 
 * @type {Array}
 */
var urls=[];

/** Reads urls from file and triggers processing
 *
 *  @emits processUrl
 */
var readUrlCsv = function() {

  var stream = fs.createReadStream("/home/vagrant/urls.csv");

  stream.on('error',function(e){ // always handle errors!!
    console.error('failed to createReadStream: %s',e);
    process.exit(-1);
  });

  var csvStream = csv()
    .on("data", function(data) {
      // data[0]: table id, data[1]: page type, data[2]: url
      urls.push(data);        
    })
    .on("end", function(){
       console.log("done reading csv");
       //console.log(urls);
       emitter.emit('processUrl'); // start processing URLs
    })
    .on('error',function(e){
      console.error('failed to parse CSV: %s',e);
      process.exit(-1);
    });

  // no return required since we don't do anything with the result
  stream.pipe(csvStream);
};

/** Event handler to process a single URL
 *
 * @emits processUrl
 */
var onProcessUrl=function(){

  // always check your assumptions
  assert(Array.isArray(urls),'urls must be an array');

  var urlRecord=urls.shift();

  if(urlRecord){

    assert(Array.isArray(urlRecord),'urlRecord must be an array');

    assert(urlRecord.length>2,'urlRecord must have at least three elements');

    penthouse(
      { 
        // ... 
      }, 
      function(e,criticalCss){
        if(e){
          console.error('failed to process record %s: %s',urlRecord,e);
          return; // IMPORTANT! do not drop through to rest of func!
        }

        // do what you need with the result here

        if(urls.length===0){ // ok, we're done
          console.log('completed processing URLs');
          return;
        }

        emitter.emit('processUrl'); 
      }
    );
  }
}

/**
  * processUrl event - triggers processing of next URL
  *
  * @event processUrl
  */
emitter.on('processUrl',onProcessUrl); // assign handler

// start everything going...
readUrlCsv();
```

The benefit of using events here rather than your solution is the lack of recursion which can easily overwhelm your stack.

***Hint**: You can use events to handle all program flow issues normally addressed by Promises or modules like `async`.*

And since events are at the very heart of Node (the "event loop"), it's really the best, most efficient way to solve such problems.

It's both elegant and "The Node Way"!

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/raisch/2751f605f75cf9383748) that illustrates the technique, without relying on streams or `penthouse`, the output of which is:

```
url: url1
RESULT: RESULT FOR url1
url: url2
RESULT: RESULT FOR url2
url: url3
RESULT: RESULT FOR url3
completed processing URLs
```

Comment: That makes sense. I tried multiple versions of what you suggest but still unable to get it to work correctly. See my update in OP.

Comment: In `buildCriticalCss`, what do you see when you `//console.log(urls);`? - which might be better written with `console.dump`.

Comment: `console.dump(urls)` didn't show me anything, but `console.log(urls)` output the array of rows from the CSV correctly. It's weird now...First time I ran it, I got the memory dump warning and it stopped. 2nd time, it started going through each row (I printed `console.log(data)` to prove it was looping). But it never finishes any of them. Watching the console, I never see this get printed `console.log('do we ever finish one?');`

Comment: Well, as noted below, it's probably related to the fact that you're processing _**all**_ of your URLs at the same time. In a moment, I'll update my answer with a simple event-based solution that will process your URLs sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using console.logs which usually is enough, you can also use the built in debugger: https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

Another thing you can do is go into the node_modules/penthouse directory and add your console.logs or `debugger` statement into the code for that module.  That way you can debug your program there rather than the module just being a black box.

Also make sure there isn't some kind of race condition where for example the CSV doesn't always get output before it tries to read them in.

I think that the memory leak issue is probably a red herring as far as making your code function.

From your comment it sounds like you want to do something like the following with `async.mapSeries`: http://promise-nuggets.github.io/articles/15-map-in-series.html You could also use promises as it shows or even after getting promises set up use the `async/await` stuff with a regular for loop after compiling with babel.  In the long run I recommend doing that sort of thing with `async/await` and babel but that might be overkill just to get this working.

Comment: Yeah I did add a console.log to almost every method in the `penthouse/lib/index.js` file, and the last one that is written is on line 51 right before the spawn command. What it looks like I need to do is tell the gulpfile to only process one row at a time. Wait until pentouse has processed the first row/url before moving to the 2nd. That's where I am stuck in how to do that. Because it spawns a child process, that's probably why the lop on CSV rows continues, and it doesn't wait for the first process to finish.

Comment: OK see edits, I linked to a useful async.mapSeries example.

Comment: I am going to read more about promise and the example you just sent, as that looks like something I need for my project. I added a simple solution to the end of my question.